# Rust collect() chunks of a vector into Vec<Vec<bool>>

Tags: vector, rust, collect

I have a vector `outputs` of u64 which basically only has 0s and 1s. And I want to split the vector into equal parts to get a `Vec<Vec<bool>>` or `Vec<&[bool]]`.

However, somehow I can't do it it tells me

```
256  |                     .collect();
     |                      ^^^^^^^ value of type `std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<bool>>` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=bool>`
```

using

```
                let sqrt_output = (outputs.len() as f64).sqrt() as usize;
                let output_grid: Vec<&[bool]> = outputs
                    .chunks(sqrt_output)
                    .map(|s| {
                        match s {
                            [1_u64] => true,
                            [0_u64] => false,
                            // this is a hack but I don't know how to return an error ...
                            _ => true,
                        }
                    })
                    .collect();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get back a `Vec<Vec<bool>>` your `map` closure would need to return a `Vec<bool>`

Here's an example:

```rust
fn main() {
    let outputs: Vec<u64> = vec![0, 1, 1, 0];
    let output_grid: Vec<Vec<bool>> = outputs
        .chunks(2)
        .map(|s| {  // this is an &[u64]
            let mut inner_vec = Vec::new();
            for val in s {
                inner_vec.push(match val {
                    1 => true,
                    0 => false,
                    _ => panic!("illegal number") // can just avoid push-ing if you want to ignore other numbers
                })
            }
            inner_vec
        })
        .collect();
    // this prints "[[false, true], [true, false]]"
    println!("{:?}", output_grid)
}
```

Comment: Amazing help. Thanks a lot. I even understand why (which is rare in Rust ... by I am getting better)